# Prove that $L = \{a^rb^qc^q\}$ where $q > 0$, $r \geq 0$ is not a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, computability, pumping-lemma

I've been working on this question for a few hours now and I've been trying to figure out the question above. My biggest problem is that I don't know what to do with the $>$ and $\geq$ symbols when determining the language. My current work is below. Also, if you have any resources on how to adequately learn pumping lemma it would be really appreciated, I'm trying to find examples that don't set specific values to $p$ because it's an arbitrary number.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/451092252396224516/1038268572750856263/20221104_214824.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Comment: Not completely? I'm struggling to understand how to write a proof for that specific problem

Comment: You asked for resources to learn the pumping lemma, there is a detailed explaination and detailed example that looks very much like your language.

Comment: Also note that you are allowed to choose $r = 0$ (which would simplify your proof).

Comment: Please don't link to external images, as if that link stops working, then the question becomes useless.  Don't use images for text or mathematics. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't worked it out yet, here's my best explanation.

---

Firstly, notice how we can have any number of $a$ characters at the start. So, to make life easy let's assume we have none. If we then let $w=b^pc^p$, we can see that this is part of $L$ (when $r=0$ and $q=p$).

We then take a look at the conditions for a regular language under the pumping lemma. If the language is regular, we can take any $w\in L$ and decompose it into $xyz$ where:

- $|y|\geq1$
- $|xy|<p$
- $xy^nz\in L\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0$

If we go back to $w=b^pc^p$, we can see that because $|xy|\leq p$, $xy$ has to be made up of entirely the character $b$ otherwise $|xy|>p$. This means that $y$ must be made up of at least 1 $b$ (because $|y|\geq1$) and at most $p$ repetitions of $b$.

We then have a look at the last condition of the pumping lemma; $xy^nz\in L\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Since $y$ is made up of only repetitions of $b$, any repetition of $y$ will add more of the character $b$ into this new word. This means that $xy^nz\notin L$ when $n\neq 1$ and therefore the last condition of the pumping lemma is not met so $L$ is not a regular language.

Hope this was helpful in some way